# unistalling software on ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: software-uninstall

i need help to uninstall mattermost on ubuntu server 18.04

first of all here is how i installed the app:

```
wget https://releases.mattermost.com/5.1.0/mattermost-5.1.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Extract the Mattermost Server files.

```
tar -xvzf mattermost*.gz
```

Move the extracted file to the /opt directory.

```
sudo mv mattermost /opt
```

Create the storage directory for files.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/mattermost/data
```

..... Now i tried to unsinstall it using:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge mattermost
```

and it didn't work.(error: unable to locate package mattermost)

Comment: Since you didn't use apt to install the software, you cannot use apt to remove the software. Apt is not omniscient - it only knows about deb packages...but you didn't install a deb package. You installed something else. Look in your originall tarball for an INSTALL or README file. How to install AND uninstall should be explained in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse of

```
sudo mv mattermost /opt
```

is

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/mattermost
```

Mind though that a source install tends to have a document in the directory explaining how to uninstall (so check for a readme or uninstall document in `/opt/mattermost/`) as that should take precedence over the `rm` command.

Also make sure if there is a service you stop it first.

Remove the service with:

```
rm /lib/systemd/system/mattermost.service

systemctl daemon-reload
```